# undefined method `delegate_method_as' for Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: jekyll

I have a problem with jekyll when I do a jekyll serve I have the following error that appears:

```
~/agency-jekyll-theme-gh-pages$ jekyll serve --trace --incremental
Traceback (most recent call last):
    14: from /home/yossef/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    13: from /home/yossef/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    12: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
     9: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:191:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
     7: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
     6: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:4:in `<module:Jekyll>'
     1: from /home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:5:in `<module:Drops>'
/home/yossef/gems/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:10:in `<class:CollectionDrop>': undefined method `delegate_method_as' for Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the `collection_drop` gem. Are your gems up-to-date? What happens when you run `bundle` or `bundle update`?

Comment: I solved the problem by reinstalling jekyll.

Comment: I tried reinstalling, but it didn't help. I seem to have the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220028/undefined-method-delegate-method-as-for-jekylldropscollectiondropclass-n

Comment: @yoyo348 - what version of jekyll did you re-install and how?

Comment: @mpersico i dont remember exactly but have you trying a : sudo bundle exec jekyll serve ?