# undefined method `delegate_method_as' for Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop:Class (NoMethodError) Did you mean? DelegateClass

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler

When I try to update my jekyll project on our debian buster server, I get this error:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    11: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:191:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `require'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:4:in `<module:Jekyll>'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:5:in `<module:Drops>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/drops/collection_drop.rb:10:in `<class:CollectionDrop>': undefined method `delegate_method_as' for Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  DelegateClass
```

The same with just `jekyll build`.

I already tried this too:

```
bundle update
```

It used to work like this a few months ago.

My project is this: https://github.com/freifunk-kiel/startseite/blob/master/Gemfile

I tried to reinstall jekyll:

```
PACKAGES="$(dpkg -l |grep jekyll|cut -d" " -f3|xargs )"
apt remove --purge $PACKAGES
```

I had these packages

```
jekyll ruby-jekyll-coffeescript ruby-jekyll-feed ruby-jekyll-gist ruby-jekyll-paginate ruby-jekyll-sass-converter ruby-jekyll-watch
```

then reinstall:

```
apt install jekyll
```

this will install the same packages again:

```
jekyll ruby-jekyll-coffeescript ruby-jekyll-feed ruby-jekyll-gist ruby-jekyll-paginate ruby-jekyll-sass-converter ruby-jekyll-watch
```

But this didn't help either

---

UPDATE:

I also tried uninstall all jekyll packages and then install newer jekyll version with

```
gem install jekyll jekyll-feed jekyll-gist jekyll-paginate jekyll-sass-converter jekyll-coffeescript
```

but this gives me another error:

```
# jekyll build --trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
        27: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        26: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        25: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
        24: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        23: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        22: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll.rb:195:in `<top (required)>'
        21: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        20: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        19: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.1.0/lib/jekyll-sass-converter.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        16: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.1.0/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        13: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
        11: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         9: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         6: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi/ffi.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi/platform.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi/platform.rb:37:in `<module:FFI>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi/platform.rb:57:in `<module:Platform>': uninitialized constant FFI::Platform::CPU (NameError)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Uninstall the apt version of jekyll with:

   ```
   PACKAGES="$(dpkg -l |grep jekyll|cut -d" " -f3|xargs )"
   sudo apt remove --purge $PACKAGES
   ```
2. IMPORTANT! Clean-up your dependency libs after uninstalling all debian packages:

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
3. Then install all needed jekyll packages via gem, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo gem install jekyll jekyll-feed jekyll-gist jekyll-paginate jekyll-sass-converter jekyll-coffeescript
   ```
4. Then in your project directory run:

   ```
   bundle update
   ```

Answer (score 0):

After **uninstalling**, try to install Jekyll as ruby gem:

> gem install jekyll

this is the only thing that helped me out

Comment: thx, this installs a newer version, but you also have to install all other packages as gems with `gem install jekyll jekyll-feed jekyll-gist jekyll-paginate jekyll-sass-converter jekyll-coffeescript` – anyway, it changed the error, but didn't help either. (see my update above)